# Is it possible to measure linear velocity with 3DM-GX1 model IMU on ROS?

Tags: ros, imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to know that Is possible to measure linear velocity with 3DM-GX1 model IMU on ROS? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279473/is-it-possible-to-measure-linear-velocity-with-3dm-gx1-model-imu-on-ros?/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know IMUs don't measure velocities, but measure accelerations (correct me if I'm wrong). So, you'd have to calculate as shown in your other question #q279067

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0